# Intersecting Family 2

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that, if $k$ divides $n$ and $n\ge3k$, then any intersecting family of size $n-1\choose k-1$ of $k-$ subsets of the $n-$ set $X$ consists of all $k-$ sets containing some point of $X.$

I am having trouble understanding combinatorics question. I re-read them like ten times and I still don't know what it's asking.

We have that $X = \{1,\dots,n\} \ $ and we have the condition, $k$ divides $n$ and $n\ge3k$. Also, the size of our intersecting family is $n-1\choose k-1$, but what does the question mean by, "size $n-1\choose k-1$ of $k-$ subsets of the $n-$ set $X$ consists of all $k-$ sets containing some point of $X$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to parse it is that there exists an element $x\in X$ such that your set of subsets must be the $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ subsets $S \subset X$ such that $|S| = k$ and $x\in S$.

For instance, if $X = \{1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, and $k = 2$, then $S$ could be something of the form "the subsets of size $2$ containing $1$", ie $S = \{\{1, 2\},\{1, 3\}, \{1, 4\}, \{1, 5\}, \{1, 6\}\}$.  In this case there are exactly five other possible choices for $S$, replacing the role of $1$ with some other element of $X$.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: If the given conditions are satisfied, then the result is a constraint on what $S$ can be.  Here $n = 7$ and if we set $k=2$ again, then the result is that any intersecting set $S$ consisting of $6$ subsets of $X$ of order $2$ will be of the described form.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!

Comment: Rolf, how will I be able to prove this? My book's proof didn't make sense to me.

Comment: I'm afraid the only proof I've managed to scrape together is not particularly easy (although I think it improves the bound $n \ge 3k$ to $n > 2k$), and relies on carefully examining Katona's proof of the [Erdős–Ko–Rado theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem), which is to say that your book's approach might be easier, I don't know

Comment: I see, I will look up Erdos theorem. Thanks anyways!